# Route class: before route filter

Tags: laravel-4, routes

My class filter doesn't work as expected, but I'm not certain why.
The route looks as follows:

```
//Filter checks if the user is currently authenticated 
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() { 
    Route::resource('organisers', 'OrganiserController'); 
});
```

The filter class was properly linked:
    Route::filter('auth', 'AuthFilter');

The filter class is also called as expected.
What is strange is that when the filter class returns an object (json response), it is immediately sent back to the client.

If I don't send back anything from the filter class (if there is no error), then Laravel4 throws an error, instead of executing the OrganiserController index method.
The url jumps to /login, but I have no idea why.

The error looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `auth` filter is actually working as expected. If you return anything from a filter (besides a `return Redirect`), Laravel sends that response to the browser and ends your request. If a user is not logged in, then the `auth` filter redirects to a `/login` route, which should contain your login page.

You can change the behavior of `auth` in `app/filters.php`, but at the moment it's trying to find a login page that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I'm building a REST api, and developed a custom auth class to handle the incoming requests myself. I changed the filter name to api.auth instead of auth, and now it works perfectly.